# ELK: I cannot add logs from another server

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat

I have configured ELK, everything works. Also configured filebeat and it also transfers data to logstash.

After that I wanted to configure my other server to also forward the logs. Installed filebeat on it and added the following configuration

```
# ============================== Filebeat inputs ===============================

filebeat.inputs:

# Each - is an input. Most options can be set at the input level, so
# you can use different inputs for various configurations.
# Below are the input specific configurations.

# filestream is an input for collecting log messages from files.
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/*.log
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /var/log/syslog
```

But I only have the first server in Kabana. Run `filebeat test output`

```
logstash: 10.0.10.42:5044...
  connection...
    parse host... OK
    dns lookup... OK
    addresses: 10.0.10.42
    dial up... OK
  TLS... WARN secure connection disabled
  talk to server... OK
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: filebeat.yml, filebeat test output have missing parts. If you can share full part maybe I can help